# LESS: Compiler that merges and minifies all imported files

Tags: compiler-construction, less

I have a complex nested tree of .less files organized as a main.less file that imports several other secondary files with @import clause. In some cases, these files import other ones.

For the moment I am in development mode, and files are compiled at runtime by LESS.JS compiler, but in production environment I would like to compile once all files and maybe merge all files alltogether. How to obtain this?

My intention would be:

1. When I'll be ready for production, pass main.less path to a compiler
2. Compiler analyzes main.less and if it encounters an @import clause, follows the link and compiles also imported file.
3. This should be iterated for all files
4. Finally I would like to have only one big .css file that is the merging (and maybe minimized) of all single .less files.

I tried SimpLESS compiler but it does not generate what I'm asking....

Comment: I may be missing something here, but what you describe as your 'intention' should be the default of what any LESS compiler puts out. In compiling `main.less` it should produce a `main.css` that is exactly as you describe, with all `@import` clauses resolved into css as well as they are located in `main.less`. What do you get instead (what is missing)?

Comment: Reading around here on SO, I found that I must load in SimpLESS only main.less and not the entire project folder in order to compile a single big .css file.

Anyway, it is strange that it can show me a syntax error in an imported file, that .JS runtime compiler correctly compile.... very strange, it concern to this kind of syntax 
p:nth-child(@{number_objects}n+1)

Comment: SimpLESS just uses an outdated Less version (i.e. consider using some more or less up-to-date alternative).

Comment: Thanks. What do you suggest?

Comment: Use the command line compiler bundled with LESS. `npm install -g less`

Comment: Can I use it also in Windows environment? if yes... I have to enter in cmd prompt, and then? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found "[LESS.js - Windows](https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows)" that it works perfectly, even if is not graphical but only shell based.
It's practically immediate in compiling and does not return errors in my less code (unlike all other graphical tools that I tested with the same code, such as WinLess and SimpLess).

It is very similar to "node.js based" compiling tool, but it does not require any other package to be installed. Just download it and use it stand-alone. The only drawback is that last update is since beginning of 2014, so it could be outdated respect last new features of language.